# Dash plotly, input autosugestions

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

When typing a word in a dash input I would like to get autosuggestions, an example of what I mean is this CLI app I made in the past.

[image]

a link to the documentation: https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/asking_for_input.html?highlight=suggestions#autocompletion 3

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AutoComplete component from [this module](https://github.com/StratoDem/sd-material-ui). There's an example of it being [in this file](https://github.com/StratoDem/sd-material-ui/blob/master/usage.py).

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here where I populate a list of city/state suggestions via google api, I think you can use this same structure for your own application: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671216/14244758